# Minimizing the operator norm of a sum of matrices

Tags: matrix-analysis, operator-norms

Given an $m\times n$ real matrix $C$.

Let $a_i\in\{-1,1\}$ and $b_i\in\{-1,1\}$. Consider
$$q=\left\|\text{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_m)C + C\text{diag}(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\right\|$$
where the norm is the induced 2-norm $\|m\|=\text{max}_{|x|_2=1}|mx|_2$

The minimum possible value of $q$ is of course $0$, when all $a_i$ are 1 and all $b_i$ are $-1$ (or vice versa). The maximum possible value of $q$ is $2\|C\|$, when all $a_i=b_i=1$.

> **Question**: what is the *second* smallest value $q$ could have? The answer will depend on $C$. I am looking for a way to calculate this, an algorithm, preferably one that doesn't require trying all $2^{m+n}$ possibilities.

**Thoughts and background**

The problem is symmetric $a_i\rightarrow-a_i$,$b_i\rightarrow-b_i$ gives the same $q$. Even making use of this, the naive algorithm is still $O(2^{m+n-1})$.

$q$ can be written in terms of the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) as well:
$$q=\|C\circ M\|$$
$$M_{ij}=a_i+b_j$$
The matrices $C$ of interest here are not easily characterizable, but they are always sparse ($O(1)$ nonzero elements per row and per column). The simplest $C$ of practical interest is
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
for which the second-smallest $q$, let us call it $q_2$, is $2$ (I tried all $2^{12}$ possibilities). This is attained when $[a_1,\ldots,a_m]=[-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1]$ and $[b_1,\ldots,b_n]=[-1,1,-1,1]$:
$$q_2=\left\|
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right\|=2$$